# How to perform soft assert in protractor cucumber

Tags: protractor, chai, cucumberjs

```
    defineSupportCode(({Given, When,Then})=>{

      When('click on search button', async () =>{
        await browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();
        await browser.sleep(3000)
        await browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();
        await browser.sleep(3000)
        let element1 = element(by.xpath("//h3[text()='Selenium - Web Browser Automation']"))
        await expect(element1.isDisplayed()).to.eventually.be.false;
      });


      Then('it should show search result', async () =>{
        let element2 = element(by.xpath("//h3[text()='Downloads - Selenium']"))
        await expect(element2.isDisplayed()).to.eventually.be.true;
      });
})
```

**My last then block was skipped**.But I want to continue my all test steps even if it is pass or fail (then definitely i think i have to use soft assert).In testng we have a class called softassert. Is there something available here as well similar to that one. I am using chai package for assertion purpose

TIA

Answer (score 0):

**Background:**

This is not a protractor or cucumber issue, it is actually chai(well it looks like you are using chai from your code snippet but feel free to correct me if I'm wrong).

**Issue:**

After reviewing chai docs https://www.chaijs.com/api/assert/ it looks like they do not support the concept of soft asserts like some other assertion frameworks.

**Solution 1:**

The only workaround I can think of is to wrap your assertion in a try catch and store the error received from the assertion in your world instance, then in your after hook throw the errors.

**Solution 2:**
Use a library that does support soft asserts. From a quick search, I see https://www.npmjs.com/package/soft-assert but FYI I have not tried this library

**Notes:**
One bad thing about this is that screenshots may capture incorrect information.